# Is there two different definition of covariance?

Tags: probability

I see two different expressions of covariance and wonder whether they are different:

> $$Cov(X,Y)=\sum_i p(X=X_i,Y=Y_i)(X_i-E(X))(Y_i-E(Y))$$

and

> $$Cov(X,Y)=\sum_{(i,j)} p(X=X_i,Y=Y_j)(X_i-E(X))(Y_j-E(Y))$$

Are the two expressions for different situations? I find it confused.

Comment: Only the first expression makes sense. When you draw several variables at the same time from a joint probability distribution, covariance measures the likelihood of a pair of those variables to be simultaneously large or small. In the second case, the variables must have been drawn independently. If that was the case, they have been drawn from marginal probability distributions, and thus it is incorrect to use joint probability distribution for their integral measures such as covariance

Comment: @AleksejsFomins actually I wonder how to derive $Cov(X,Y)=0$ for independent $X,Y$ using the first expression, I think it should be the second expression to derive it.

Comment: Sorry, I think I got myself confused as well. The two definitions are completely the same, because summing over all combinations of 2 variable values (first expression) is the same as first summing over all possible values of one variable and then the other (2nd expression). The word of caution that I wrote before is about calculating the sample covariance. In that case, one should use the first expression to emphasize that both values were sampled simultaneously

Comment: @AleksejsFomins sorry I cannot well understand. The second includes $X=X_1,Y=Y_2$, but the first doesn’t. Why should they be the same?

Comment: Can you explain to me, what you think the first sum does?

Comment: @AleksejsFomins assume $X=\left\{X_1,...,X_n\right\},Y=\left\{Y_1,...Y_n\right\}$, then the first expression is $p(X=X_1,Y=Y_1)...+...+p(X=X_n,Y=Y_n)...$

Comment: @AleksejsFomins I doubt I understand wrongly.

Comment: Then your first expression is a special case of the first expression, where each X is paired with a distinct Y. In the most general case, there is a matrix of probabilities, where for each combination of X and Y there is a probability of that combination. But, when people typically write the first sum, $i$ goes over all possible combinations, not over all pairs. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance

Comment: @AleksejsFomins Then I find where I missed, thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what was wrong? Out of curiosity

Comment: @AleksejsFomins I previously acquainted with covariance for the situation $Y=f(X)$, where $Y$ depends on $X$ and they form pairs, I should use the first expression. However, for independent $X,Y$, there are much more possible combinations, I should use the second expression.

Comment: Cool, I'm happy it got resolved